# Unable to read manifest Properties\app.manifest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

While building a C#.net application in VS studio 2013 i am getting the following error

> Unable to read manifest Properties\app.manifest.Could not find file
>   C:\Project\Properties\app.manifest

In project Settings i selected option "build Project without a manifest" but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I fixed this by myself by deleting app.mainfest in visual studio which is showing up in properties folder.

Comment: The file was likely missing (not committed, etc.), you could also fix the issue by adding in a new manifest to my project. (Project->Add->New Item->App Manifest)

Answer (score 2):

Late in the party but, 
Actually this file is mentioned in cs.proj file and your project is looking for this file.

What I did is , I have removed **app.manifest** reference  in my cs.proj file as it is not needed to me , added by someone.

Open your cs.proj file in notepad and remove below mentioned line

[image]

This did the trick for me.